# How to fix (error:any)=>Observable<any> is not assignable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs6

In the `saveExpense()` method, when passing error handling `catchError (this.handleError<any>('Add Expense', []))`, this method is highlighted and the error is displayed: **`Argument type (error:any)=>Observable<any> is not assignable to parameter type (err:any, caught:Observable<T>)=>never`. How to solve?**

```js
    saveExpense(userid, oExpense) {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `${this.jwtToken}`
            })
        };
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:5555/api/expense/${userid}`, JSON.stringify(oExpense), httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(
            (response: ServerMessage) => console.log(response)
        ),
        catchError(this.handleError('Add Expense', []))
    );
}

    private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
            console.error(error);
            console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
            return of(result as T);
        };
    }
```

Comment: you are shooting yourself on the foot by using `any` where you shouldnt

Comment: I left any only in the handler but this not solve my problem

Comment: Update your question with the current error

Answer (score 0):

That statement means `catchError()` is expecting to be given a function with a signature of `(err:any, caught:Observable<T>)=>never` as a parameter.

What's the signature (parameters and return type) of the function that gets passed to `catchError()`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

saveExpense(userid, oExpense) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `${this.jwtToken}`
        })
    };
    return this.http
               .post(`http://localhost:5555/api/expense/${userid}`, JSON.stringify(oExpense), httpOptions)
               .pipe(
                   tap((response: ServerMessage) => console.log(response)),
                   catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)),
                );
}

private handleError(errorResponse): Observable<any> {
    console.log('error', errorResponse);
    return throwError(errorResponse);
}
```

I have a complete example of how to work with interceptors:
https://github.com/dedd1993/ngx-admin/blob/master/src/app/%40core/http/http.interceptor.ts